# rails form_for styling

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css

Is there a way to add styling to rails form_for and make it display inline?

Comment: You want to display the form's fields inline?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There might be a cleaner way to do this, but it works. (I tried with another nested hash, no dice)

```
 <% form_for(@model, :html => { :style => 'background-color:red;' }) do |f| %>
```

Comment: If there's a cleaner way, great ... but this works just fine for me if there isn't!  Thanks so much Andy!

Answer (score 3):

A even cleaner way would be to define the styling in an external stylesheet (like `application.css`). `form_for` creates a `<form id="something"/>` tag with an id attribute. You can of course use this id in your stylesheet(s) to apply some specific styling to the form.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a div of the appropriate class? Its a display thing, not a rails thing.

application.css:

```
.inline form { display: inline; }
```

form.html.erb

```
<div class="inline">
  <%= form....
</div>
```